# Ray tracing - glossy reflection

Tags: raytracing, reflection-rendering

Here I am again with my ray tracer for ipad. Now I'm trying to add glossy reflection to an object. How do i implement it?
I read some documentation online like these:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15462-s09/www/lec/13/lec13.pdf
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4620/2012fa/lectures/37raytracing.pdf

If I understood correctly instead of trace a single ray as for standard reflection I have to trace n ray in a random direction. **How do I get this random direction for each ray?** **How do i generate these samples?**

Comment: Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 2):

Generating random directions efficiently is a major issue, especially in GPU implementations of anything like ray tracing. In my research about the matter I've been using an implementation described [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch37.html). The solution refers to single values but can be easily applied to vectors as well. In my applications I generate random vectors using two methods:

- by repeating calls to PRNG function several times,
- using a function that produces a normally distributed vectors according to given slope value.

In both cases the base functions I use are as follows:

```
    inline __device__ unsigned _TausStep(unsigned &z, const int S1, const int S2, const int S3, const unsigned M)
    {
        unsigned b = (((z << S1) ^ z) >> S2);
        return z = (((z & M) << S3) ^ b);
    }

    inline __device__ unsigned _LCGStep(unsigned &z, const unsigned A, const unsigned C)
    {
        return z = (A * z + C);
    }

    /* Hybrid Tausworthe PRNG by NVIDIA.
       https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch37.html
     */
    inline __device__ float hybtausf(uint4 &z)
    {
       return 2.3283064365387e-10 * (
            _TausStep(z.x, 13, 19, 12, 4294967294UL) ^
            _TausStep(z.y, 2, 25, 4, 4294967288UL) ^
            _TausStep(z.z, 3, 11, 17, 4294967280UL) ^ 
            _LCGStep(z.w, 1664525, 1013904223UL)
        );
    }
```

The `hybtausf` function is what I use as a PRNG function. It is used both in the multiple calls random vectors generation, as in the following function, that implements the second method:

```
    // Pseudo-random, normally distributed ray direction generator.
    __device__ float3 prrg(float3 dir, float n, float4 &seed)
    {
        uint4 z = make_uint4(seed.x, seed.y, seed.z, seed.w);
        float u0 = hybtausf(z);
        float u1 = hybtausf(z);
        float3 w = normalize(dir);
        float3 t = w;

        w = fabs(w);

        seed = make_float4(z);

        if (w.x < w.y) {
            if (w.x < w.z) t.x = 1.0f;
            else t.z = 1.0f;
        } else if (w.y < w.z) t.y = 1.0f;
        else t.z = 1.0f;

        w = normalize(dir);
        float3 u = normalize(cross(t, w));
        float3 v = cross(w, u);

        float theta = acos(pow(1.0f - u0, 1.0f / (1.0f + n)));
        float phi = 2.0f * PI * u1;
        float3 a = make_float3(cos(phi)*sin(theta), sin(phi)*sin(theta), cos(theta));
        float3 R[3] = { make_float3(u.x, v.x, w.x), make_float3(u.y, v.y, w.y), make_float3(u.z, v.z, w.z) };

        return mult(a, R);
    }
```

The `n` parameter controls the mentioned "slope" of the distribution function, while `dir` is a "reference direction" around which a new direction will be generated. This method allows to generate the following overall outcome images of my implementation of path tracing (notice the reflection on the sphere):

[image: CIRT path tracing]

The image is a bit grainy but that is because I haven't yet applied proper importance sampling in the particular case.

I hope that helps.